# Error quoting spaces to locate destination filepath WinSCP script issue

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I've written a basic `.bat` file script that automates downloading a group of files via WinSCP. I have used this code for performing a similar process which is working as intended, however the stumbling block appears to be the destination filepath. I have tried using

```
C:\Users\"John Smith"\Dropbox\joebloggs\Data\"System Data"\"Raw Feeds"\Stock\May\
```

and other variations with the whole filepath within inverted commas also. If anyone could advise the correct syntax for entering this filepath it would be appreciated. Code is as follows:-

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\Users\John Smith\Documents\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
  "open sftp://joebloggs:%%40faNliGHT4@82.121.124.146/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 1024 01:01:dd:1c:54:72:98:c7:42:f9:15:8e:30:8c:66:3b"" -passive=0" ^
    ^
    "get "/*.txt" "C:\Users\John Smith\Dropbox\joebloggs\Data\System Data\Raw Feeds\Stock\May\" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

Error Log is as follows:-

```
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.902 Access is denied
. 2016-05-16 13:32:43.902 Asking user:
. 2016-05-16 13:32:43.902 Can't create file 'C:\Users\John.filepart'. ("System Error.  Code: 5.

> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.902 Access is denied")
< 2016-05-16 13:32:43.902 Script: Can't create file 'C:\Users\John.filepart'.
< 2016-05-16 13:32:43.902 Script: System Error.  Code: 5.

> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.902 Access is denied

> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 23, Number: 2052
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 (EScpSkipFile) Can't create file 'C:\Users\Daniel.filepart'.
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 System Error.  Code: 5.
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 Access is denied
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 Script: Failed
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 Script: Exit code: 1
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 Closing connection.
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 Sending special code: 12
> 2016-05-16 13:32:43.903 Sent EOF message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have to double the double quotes. You are also missing a quote at the end of the `get` command (note the three consecutive quotes).

```
"get ""/*.txt"" ""C:\Users\John Smith\Dropbox\joebloggs\Data\System Data\...\""" ^
```

*(path shortened so that it fits in view)*

See [WinSCP documentation on command-line syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax) and [FAQ Why are some WinSCP scripting commands specified in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)

---

You can also  have [WinSCP GUI generate a SFTP batch file template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating), including correct quotes.